# Converting Decimal to float gives warning unexpected type Decimal

Tags: python, type-conversion, pycharm, decimal

somewhere in my code I have the following line

```
lambda el: float(el) if isinstance(el, Decimal) else el
```

My ide (pycharm) warns me the following

> Unexpected type: Decimal

The conversion seems to work without a problem. I am wondering, is this a false alarm? Or should I be careful with Decimal to Float conversions?

Also the message seems like it indicates error and I would expect the code to break just by reading the message. Which is not the case.

Comment: By the way, do you intend to raise an exception? Your code will only return the object TypeError.

Comment: Can you precise the version of Pycharm, decimal, python? If I do `float(decimal.Decimal(3))' I do not get any warning in PyCharm 2017.2.3, Python 3.6.2, and decimal 1.70

Comment: @Reti43 good catch, I meant to `raise TypeError`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23391) was fixed in PyCharm 2017.2.3.